# How to set a Jenkins pipeline stage to unstable based on a script exit code?

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

A stage in my Jenkins pipeline should be set as unstable depending on the exit code of the script within its steps: 2 should set the stage status to unstable when 1 should set the stage result to failed.

How to achieve this? I checked "catchError" but it doesn't seem to differenciate between failed status, offering only a way to catch non 0 exit (1,2...).

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
         string(name: 'FOO', defaultValue: 'foo', description: 'My foo param')
         string(name: 'BAR', defaultValue: 'bar', description: 'My bar param')
    }

    stages {
        stage('First') {
            steps {
                    // If "script.py" exit code is 2, set stage to unstable
                    // If "script.py" exit code is 1, set stage to failed 
                    
                       sh """
                          . ${WORKSPACE}/venv/bin/activate
                          python ${WORKSPACE}/script.py --foo ${FOO} --bar ${BAR}
                          deactivate
                       """
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Second') {
            steps {
                echo('Second step')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My answer has been updated/fixed per your requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

You will need to do the following steps

1. Place all your code into a `script` block
2. Modify `sh` to return status code
3. Use a conditional to check the status code
4. Throw and Catch an error with `catchError`. Set the build to SUCCESS and the stage to FAILURE or UNSTABLE accordingly

> I am using `error` to force the exception but you can also use `sh 'exit 1'` or `throw new Exception('')`

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
         string(name: 'FOO', defaultValue: 'foo', description: 'My foo param')
         string(name: 'BAR', defaultValue: 'bar', description: 'My bar param')
    }

    stages {
        stage('First') {
            steps {
                script {
                    
                    def pythonScript = """
                          . ${WORKSPACE}/venv/bin/activate
                          python ${WORKSPACE}/script.py --foo ${FOO} --bar ${BAR}
                          deactivate
                          """
                    
                    def statusCode = sh( script:pythonScript, returnStatus:true )
                    
                    
                    if(statusCode == 2) {
                        catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'UNSTABLE') {
                            error 'STAGE UNSTABLE'
                        }
                    } else if(statusCode == 1) {
                        catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                            error 'STAGE FAILURE'
                        }
                    }
                            
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I need to set the stage result as UNSTABLE, not the whole build.

Comment: @donmelchior please let me know if this update satisfies your requirements.  I realize you said you attempted `catchError`, but it doesn't look like you put `catchError` in conditionals and you were not getting the return code to compare against

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thanks

Comment: this doesn't seem to want to work nicely within a function

Comment: @mike01010 it’s a declarative Jenkins domain specific code. You can’t put it in a Groovy function